# How do I get get any element from a given link?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

How do I get the value of **any** class or id from a given link in Javascript? Here is an image explaining what I want to do:

[image]

I'm asking to find out the value (or text) inside a specific id or class in a link. Let's say I gave Javascript a link. I want it to go to that link and find the value of a given class or id. **Let's say** I gave it the link of `google.com` and also gave it the class of `"Fx4vi"`, and it would return `"Advertising"`.

If you need to put this question on hold, can you tell me why so I can fix it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking... Say you have an `<a href="https://www.google.com">` link to the website `www.google.com`. Are you asking how you could find out the ID of the search field?

Comment: Google "web scraping".

Comment: I'm asking to find out the value (or text) inside a specific id or class in a link. Let's say I gave Javascript a link. I want it to go to that link and find the value of a given class or id. Let's say I gave it the link of https://www.google.com and also gave it the class of "Fx4vi", and it would return "Advertising". I'll update this question with an image showing the class I just stated. Give me a minute or two. I'll let you know when I'm done.

Comment: Done. I hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) you cannot load anything from Google to your site.

But if you want to get classes and ids from other .html or .php on your server you can use this:

```
let file_path = "FILE_PATH";

let xhrG = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrG.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    console.log(xhrG.readyState,xhrG.status); 
    if(xhrG.readyState === 4 && xhrG.status === 200){
        ret = xhrG.responseText;
        let temp = document.createElement('div');
        temp.id = 'idofcontainer';
        temp.innerHTML = ret;
        temp.style.display = "none";
        document.body.append(temp);

        console.log(document.getElementById('idofcontainer').getElementsByClassName('searching-by-class')); // Shows all elements with class `searching-by-class`
        console.log(document.getElementById('idofcontainer').children.namedItem('searching-by-id')); // Shows element with id`searching-by-id`
    }
}

xhrG.open("GET", file_path);
xhrG.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you want. Is it your own page or is it a page from Google?

**May be** you use the Google page screenshot **only for example** and you want to get this value from **your own page**, then you could get it like follows:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(e)
{
    var spanElement = document.querySelector('#fsl'), //<span id="fsl">
        firstElementWithClassFx4vi = spanElement.querySelector('.Fx4vi'),
        allElementsWithClassFx4vi = spanElement.querySelectorAll('.Fx4vi');

    console.log(firstElementWithClassFx4vi.innerHTML);
    console.log('In span element with id="fsl" we have: ' + allElementsWithClassFx4vi.length + ' elements.');
});
```

```html
<span id="fsl">
    <a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com">Advertising</a><br>
    <a class="Fx4vi" href="https://www.google.com">Business</a>
</span>
```

But if you want to read from Google page directly, then you have to do a request to your server  like PHP using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX). On the server side at first you could get the content from full page with [PHP function `file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php): `$content_google_page = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/');` and then you have to parse this content with Regular Expressions using [PHP function `preg-match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). After this you could give this "[web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)" content as an answer for the AJAX request.